# How to set documentation for custom components?

Tags: install4j

How can I set up the documentation for our custom components and actions so that they will be displayed at the IDE? The same goes for the variable names of these classes. Now the will be displayed like `variableName` instead of `Variable Name`.

Thanks in advance
Hardie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with BeanInfo classes.

Look at samples/customCode/src/ManyFeaturesActionBeanInfo.java for an example. That BeanInfo class describes the properties for the class defined in ManyFeaturesAction.java.